# Finite dimensional field extension, finitely many intermediate fields

Tags: field-theory

Good morning,
My question is the following:
Does every finite dimensional field extension have finitely many intermediate fields?
I thought about it quite a while and know that the following is true:
For a separable field extension there are only finitely many intermediate fields.
Is there any example for a finite dimensional non-separable field extension with infinitely many intermediate fields?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: yes there is an example : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/526000/intermediate-fields-between-mathbbz-2-sqrtx-sqrty-and-mathbbz-2