# Field extension $\mathbb{F}_p(X^p,Y^p)\subset\mathbb{F}_p(X,Y)$ not a primitive extension

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

How do I prove that $\mathbb{F}_p(X^p,Y^p)\subset\mathbb{F}_p(X,Y)$ is not a primitive extension?

And how can I give infinitely many fields $E$ such that $\mathbb{F}_p(X^p,Y^p)\subset E\subset\mathbb{F}_p(X,Y)$?

Comment: your second question is practically answered (for $p=2$) in http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/526000/intermediate-fields-between-mathbbz-2-sqrtx-sqrty-and-mathbbz-2

Comment: @mercio But that is specifically for $p=2$, how would I adapt it for general $p$?

Answer (score 0):

This happens to be written on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_element_theorem#Counterexamples): prove that any element in $\mathbb{F}_p(x,y)$ has degree $p$ over $\mathbb{F}_p(x^p,y^p)$.

Comment: And what about the fields $E$?